# CSS not complete when react app deployed in production

Tags: reactjs

I am currently working on a react, working perfectly in local, the CSS seems to be broken in production, even when using the "normal" production deployment tuto made by react [here](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/)

[local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fqUdn.png)

[remote](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hksX.png)

node, npm and yarn versions are the same locally and remotly ... remote is debian, local is mac

I do not understand ...

Anyone had the same issue maybe ? :)

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! It seems you question will need some adjustments to help you get the best support the community can offer.
Please look at [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) and how to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) links. This will help to get useful answers.

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer ;) duplicate library, if anyone has

in package.json, if you declare @material-ui/core, you do not need to import @material-ui/styles

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked in debug console from browser whether CSS files are loaded or not? Also by normal deployment do you mean production build served locally or remotely?
Please check network request made from console, sources and other part too.

Comment: Thx for your answer, deployment build is rab on a remote server, and local production build works as good as local dev build .... Css seems to be loader except manifest.json

Comment: The problem here seems on deployment process. Where have you deployed your code? Have you deployed all your build folder to remote or used some other method? Try deploying in other hosting or try another way of deployment to check whether the result will be same or not.